# Does Jiub's Opus page 9 eventually reappear? 

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

It's not anywhere in the maze tower or on the floor of the maze tower, not near the portal, not anywhere around the chest at the top or in the chest and it's not on the ground on the outside of the tower.

I've been looking for this for days. Left Soul Cairn and came back, quit game and came back, looked around again - nothing. I have to keep all the other letters in my book inventory until I finish the quest.

Does Jiub's Opus page 9 eventually reappear?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on your computer open console commands and type TCL and run downwards ontop of the maze. Clip thru the ground and look up at the floor beneath the chest. The note will be there it's just clipped under the floor (bug I guess). You'll be able to pick up the note, levitate a little above the ground somewhere and type TCL again to toggle it off.

You really have to play Bethesda games on the computer so you and other modders can make their games playable thru all the bugs.